# Love for Country Hadith

Tags: hadith, authenticity, uloom-al-hadith

Is the frequently quoted Hadith authentic?
**"حب الوطن من الایمان"**

Comment: I've never ever heard of this narration and I doubt it being authentic hadith. As love for the country is similar to love for money or oneself etc. which is rather given by birth and has no direct link to faith. To the contrary Allah says in the context of disbelievers: "And if We had decreed upon them, "Kill yourselves" or "Leave your homes," they would not have done it, except for a few of them. But if they had done what they were instructed, it would have been better for them and a firmer position [for them in faith]." [4:66](https://legacy.quran.com/4/66)

Answer (score 1):

**No, this is a fabricated hadith.**

The scholars have mentioned that this is a (Mawdoo) fabricated hadith.

*Shaykh al-Albani* (May Allah have mercy on him), mentioned about this hadith in “*al-Silsilah al-Hadeeth ad-Da’eefah*” (Volume 1, page 110 number 36), and classed it as being Mawdoo’ (fabricated).

*Shaykh Muhammad ibn Saalih al-Uthaymeen* (May Allah have mercy on him) said:
**ومثله “حب الوطن من الإيمان” وهو مشهور عند العامة على أنه حديث صحيح، وهو حديث موضوع مكذوب، بل المعنى أيضاً غير صحيح بل حب الوطن من التعصب.**

“Like for example ‘Love for one’s homeland is from faith’. It is famous near the general people, that this is a Saheeh hadith, (but) this hadith is fabricated and false. It’s meaning is also not correct, rather, love of one’s homeland is from prejudice.”
Source: “Sharh al-Manzuma al-Bayquniyya fee Mustalah al-Hadith” - Page 70